# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_custom_column_class() in helpers.php when activating updated plugin

Tags: php, methods, wordpress, fatal-error

I need help figuring out this the undefined function error `get_custom_column_class()`

```
if( ! function_exists( 'haze_translateColumnWidthToSpan' ) ) :

    function haze_translateColumnWidthToSpan($width, $front = true) {
        if(preg_match('/^(\d{1,2})\/12$/', $width, $match)) {
            $w = "col-md-".$match[1];
        } else {
            switch ( $width ) {
                case "1/6" :
                    $w = "col-sm-2";
                    break;
                case "1/4" :
                    $w = "col-sm-3";
                    break;
                case "1/3" :
                    $w = "col-sm-4";
                    break;
                case "1/2" :
                    $w = "col-sm-6";
                    break;
                case "2/3" :
                    $w = "col-sm-8";
                    break;
                case "3/4" :
                    $w = "col-sm-9";
                    break;
                case "5/6" :
                    $w = "col-sm-10";
                    break;
                case "1/1" :
                    $w = "col-sm-12";
                    break;
                case "2/4" :
                    $w = "col-sm-6";
                    break;
                default :
                    $w = $width;
            }
        }

        $custom = $front ? get_custom_column_class($w): false;
        return $custom ? $custom : $w;
```

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: `get_custom_column_class()` isn't a WordPress function, and hasn't been defined...There's not much else that can be said about it. You need to define that function, if you want to use it.

Comment: Not familiar with WP, but a quick search on github came up with a couple of repo's that use this function (eg [this one](https://github.com/caffeinewhore/aden/blob/42e132ff44fe00c3862ea5c1e8c97b231fe8164e/wp-content/themes/portal-theme.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/composer/lib/helpers.php)). My guess is it's part of some wp plugin. Install that

Answer (score 0):

replace **haze** with **wpb**

if( ! function_exists( 'haze_translateColumnWidthToSpan' ) ) :

```
function haze_translateColumnWidthToSpan($width, $front = true) {
```

Also go to you theme folder
folder vc_templates > vc_column.php

replace **haze** with **wpb**
 on line 11 of vc_column.php

$width = haze_translateColumnWidthToSpan($width);

Just two files .